# fading effect on images which are changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to add fade effect but i don't know how...

html

```
 <body onLoad="simg()">
    <div id="slide">
        <img src="img1.jpg" id="img" >
    </div>
 </body>
```

js

```
var nrimg = 1;
var total = 6;
var timp = window.setInterval(function simg() {   
   var image = document.getElementById('img');
   nrimg = nrimg + 1;

   if(nrimg > total){nrimg = 1;}
   if(nrimg < 1){nrimg = total;}    

   image.src = "img"+ nrimg +".jpg";
},2000);
```

and css

```
#slide {
    height:400px;
    width:650px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

 #img {
    height:400px;
    width:650px;
    position:absolute;
 }
```

where to put transition? or something like that.thanks in advance. 
I'm not sure where to put the `transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;`

Comment: Currently you are just changing the src of the image, what you need to do is fade out the image first, then change the src then fade it back. The fading itself can just be a css class with `opacity: 0`, you just need to figue out when to add and remove the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a transition on the opacity, but you're not changing the opacity. In order for the transition to take effect you'd need to change the opacity of the element you would like to see the effect on. Something like this:

```
#slide {
opacity: 0.2; //inactive slide
height:400px;
width:650px;
margin: 50px auto;
position:relative;
border-radius:4px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#slide.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

 #img {
   height:400px;
    width:650px;
    position:absolute;
 }
```

so you'd have to add some random class (`active` in my example) that will allow the opacity to transition from 0.2 (when inactive) to 1 (when active)

See this link for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp